# Select the non repeating/Distinct value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select the record based on the distinct id. When i go for 'DISTINCT' it picks the duplicate record and truncates the repeating record and gives me the one left out.
How can i SQL to pick to just that record which isn't repeated ?

`INPUT`

| id | name | age | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 22 | usa |
| 1 | a | 23 | usa |
| 2 | b | 44 | uk |
| 3 | e | 33 | eu |
| 3 | f | 55 | eu |
| 8 | k | 49 | usa |

`OUTPUT`

| id | name | age | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b | 44 | uk |
| 8 | k | 49 | usa |

Comment: DISTINCT picks the duplicate value and removes one and return the remaining which destroys my purpose. that's why i decided to let my word out here for some guidance.

Comment: explain your logic for your output , It's not clear, add your query as well

Comment: are you looking for records that are not duplicated??

Comment: I don't understand the logic here at all. What happened, for example, to the rows with an `id` of `1`? Why are there no rows with the value `'eu'` for `location`?

Comment: Hi eshrivana. The output table picked the unique and non repeated id from the input tbl. the first rec 2 isn't repeated, it stands out as unique rec, same goes with id 8.

Comment: So, are you saying you want rows where there is only 1 row per ID?

Comment: yes and those which are not repeated, like the id 2 & 8 aren't repeated in the entire tbl. It's just alone. were as the rest are duplicated and many. my intention is to not address the repeated ids and go for the super unique ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok , here is how you can do it :

```
select * from (
   select * , count(*) over (partition by id) cn
   from tablename
) t
where cn = 1
```

Comment: thank you eshirvana!!! I could learn alot from experts like you. Appreciate your generosity

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Input]
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM [Input] GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve the output you're after:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SQL Common Transaction Expression** ([CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) AS FOLLOWS

```
declare @mytable as table(id int ,name nvarchar(100),age int,location nvarchar(50))

insert into @mytable values
(1,'a',22,'usa'),(1,'a',23,'usa'),(2,'b',44,'uk'),(3,'e',33,'eu'),(3,'f',55,'Tunisia'),('8','k',49,'Palestine')


with 
cte1 as(select * from @mytable),
cte2 as (select id, count(1) N from @mytable group by id),
cte3 as (select TA.id,TA.name,TA.age,TA.location from cte1 TA inner join cte2 TB on TA.id=TB.id where TB.N=1)
select * from cte3
```